# JSON schema for validating list with different possible field values

Tags: json, jsonschema

Within a JSON structure (“event bundle”), I am collecting several lists of events. These are called event lists. Each event in that list has at least a `type` field, whose value is dependent on which list it is stored in. Consider the following valid example:

```
{
    "event_bundle": {
        "alert_events": [
            { "type": "fooAlert1", "value": "bar" },
            { "type": "fooAlert2", "value": "bar" },
            { "type": "fooAlert3", "value": "bar" }
        ],
        "user_events": [
            { "type": "fooUser1", "value": "bar" },
            { "type": "fooUser2", "value": "bar" },
            { "type": "fooUser3", "value": "bar" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here, `alert_events` can only contain events whose types are `fooAlert1`, `fooAlert2` and `fooAlert3`, not others. The same goes for `user_events`. So, this JSON would *not* be valid:

```
{
    "event_bundle": {
        "alert_events": [
            { "type": "fooAlert1", "value": "bar" },
            { "type": "fooUser2", "value": "bar" },
            { "type": "foo", "value": "bar" }
        ],
        "user_events": [
            { "type": "fooAlert1", "value": "bar" },
            { "type": "fooUser2", "value": "bar" },
            { "type": "foo", "value": "bar" }
        ]
    }
}
```

It's invalid, since `fooUser2` cannot appear in an event that is in an `alert_events` list, and `fooAlert1` cannot appear in the `user_events`. Also, the event `foo` is not valid at all.

I currently have the following simple schema:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "event_list": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/event"
      }
    },
    "event": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["type", "value"],
      "properties": {
        "type": { "type": "string" },
        "value": { "type": ["string", "object"] },
        "source": { "type": ["string", "null"] }
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "event_bundle": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "alert_events": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/event_list"
        },
        "user_events": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/event_list"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, this does not fully validate the allowable `type`s.

I know I could define different `event_list`s with different `event`s, but that would mean I'd have to define potentially dozens of lists and events.

Is there an easier way to say, I want to validate that `event` objects in an `alert_events` list can have one set of `type`s, and for another list another set of types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference and use instance data as values in your validation.

What you are asking is business logic, and not to do with the "shape" of your JSON data, which is the remit of JSON Schema.

You would need to implement this as your application logic.